# Finding the smallest possible value of $|S_n|$ for Sequence and Series in real analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $_1,_2, … , _$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $(_ = 4^) =
(_ = −4^) = \frac12$. Let $_ = _1 + _2 + ⋯ + _$. If $A_n=\sup\, \{ ∈ \Bbb R: (|_| ≥ ) = 1 \}$ for $ ∈ \Bbb N$, show that $A_ = \dfrac23(4^ + 2)$?

for both extreme cases,

$S_=(4/3)(4^-1)$ and $S_=(-4/3)(4^-1)$

How to proceed with the proof after this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with probability since every arrangement has positive probability, so you are really asking: What is the smallest possible value (in absolute value) of $\sum \pm 4^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, do you have any idea on how to get An?

Comment: As in Iosif's answer below, the optimal arrangement is to take the final sign as $+$ and all the others as $-$. By the way, your question would have been much better suited (and likely better received at) https://math.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: But how to interpret sup{r∈R:P(|Sn|≥r)=1}  for n∈N? it is because from my understanding, this means the least upper bound which is actually infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$a_n:=\dfrac23(4^n + 2).$$
By the triangle inequality, with probability $1$ we have
$|S_{n-1}|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}|X_k|=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}4^k=4^n-a_n$; that is, $P(|S_{n-1}|\le4^n-a_n)=1$. The equality $X_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$ and the triangle inequality imply that on the event $\{|S_n|<a_n,|S_{n-1}|\le4^n-a_n\}$ we have
$$|X_n|\le|S_n|+|S_{n-1}|<a_n+(4^n-a_n)=4^n$$
and hence $|X_n|<4^n$. So, on the event $\{|X_n|=4^n,|S_{n-1}|\le4^n-a_n\}$ we have $|S_n|\ge a_n$. So,
$$P(|S_n|\ge a_n)\ge P(|X_n|=4^n,|S_{n-1}|\le4^n-a_n)=1,$$
because $P(|X_n|=4^n)=1$ and $P(|S_{n-1}|\le4^n-a_n)=1$.
Hence,
$$P(|S_n|\ge a_n)=1. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
On the other hand,
$$P(|S_n|=a_n)\ge P(X_n=4^n,S_{n-1}=-(4^n-a_n)) \\
=P(X_n=4^n,X_{n-1}=-4^{n-1},\dots,X_1=-4^1)=2^{-n}>0$$
and hence for all $r>a_n$ we have
$$P(|S_n|\ge r)\le P(|S_n|>a_n)\le1-2^{-n}<1. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
So,
$$A_n=a_n.\quad\Box$$

---

**Details on the conclusion $A_n=a_n$, in response to a comment by the OP:** We have
$$A_n=\sup E,\quad\text{where}\quad 
E:=\{r\in\Bbb R\colon P(|S_n|\ge r)=1\}. $$
By \eqref{2}, for any $r>a_n$ we have $r\notin E$; that is, $E\subseteq(-\infty,a_n]$. Also, by \eqref{1}, $a_n\in E$. We conclude that $\sup E=\max E=a_n$; that is, $A_n=a_n$.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For P(|Sn−1|≤4n−an)=1, I know that it is because of P(|Sn|≥an), the problem is how to get P(|Sn|≥an)? Is it by our assumption that r>an?

Comment: For triangle inequality, if Sn - Sn-1 = Xn, then |P(Sn) - P(Sn-1)| <= |P(C)|, how do I get your inequality? it seems like you are using P(Xn intersect Sn-1)

Comment: Then, why do you want to pick negative for Sn-1?

Comment: can you answer it here? Thanks in advance

john22445 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1272887/john22445), Application on Lindeberg's condition, URL (version: 2023-12-27): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4834304

Comment: (i) I have added details on your first two comments. (ii) Why "pick negative for Sn-1?" -- Because it works. (iii) I am not really active on math.stackexchange. Most of my contributions there are spillovers from MathOverflow.

Comment: I had fully understand your steps, thank you so much, but can i know the meaning of sup{r∈R:P(|Sn|≥r)=1}  for n∈N? it is because from my understanding, this means the least upper bound which is actually infinity?

Comment: @john22445 : I have added this detail as well.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, I would like to delete my post after this